# How to merge two network interface in one?

Tags: networking, openwrt, bridge, interface

I have two network interface on my router: wlan0 and wlan1. First for 2.4Ghz and second for 5Ghz. Also i have Coova-chilli with setting HS_LANIF=wlan0. Therefore captive portal (chilli) work for only one interface in same time.

I have enable both wireless network in same time and make it work together with captive portal. Can i merge these interfaces in one? May bridge i don't know. For use it as HS_LANIF=br-wlan.

I have OpenWRT system and router WDR4300.

Comment: What is the goal? You have several options here, but each depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to route traffic from one network to the other? Are both networks on the same subnet? Do you want broadcast packets from one network to get propogated to the other? Do they both have routes to the internet? Do you want to load balance internet traffic out both interfaces?

Comment: Maybe `brctl addbr br-wlan; brctl addif br-wlan wlan0; brctl addif br-wlan wlan1` could work, but i'm not sure if it would just work.

Comment: @Patrick my goal is make work both 2.4Ghz (wlan0) and 5Ghz (wlan1) wireless together with captive portal. Problem is that i can setup only one interface for captive portal, but i need both. Also i need use mac address of wlan0 interface to new interface.